# Is it natural to say "the most popular mode of transportation"?

Tags: meaning

Consider this sentence

> The subway is the most popular **mode of transportation** in my city.

Is it natural to say that?

I choose "mode" because it is the most common one in the possibilities I can imagine.

[image]

However, I'm not sure whether [all the phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=method%20of%20transportation%2Capproach%20of%20transportation%2Cform%20of%20transportation%2C%20mode%20of%20transportation&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmethod%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmethod%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMethod%20of%20Transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cform%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmode%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmode%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMode%20of%20Transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMode%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cmethod%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmethod%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMethod%20of%20Transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cform%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmode%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmode%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMode%20of%20Transportation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMode%20of%20transportation%3B%2Cc0) shown above mean the same thing. Could someone help me on this?

Comment: **Mode** is by far the most popular of the three although you might prefer one of the others in a particular context. . https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mode+of+transport%2Cmethod+of+transport%2Cform+of+transport&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmode%20of%20transport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmethod%20of%20transport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cform%20of%20transport%3B%2Cc0

Comment: method for goods, mode for people, I'd say.....

Comment: British English speakers might prefer 'transport' to 'transportation', which is mainly American, and 'travel' even more so.

Comment: I would caution that for terms of such low prevalence, NGram results are not necessarily useful; they will reflect the idiosyncrasies of the corpus rather than the language as a whole. For example, a large proportion of Google Books works are government documents (which are mostly public domain in the U.S.), and *mode* may be more common because that is the technical term.

Comment: `Mode` is a tad formal, so `form` or `type` would be more common in casual speech.

Comment: You could say "The subway is the most popular way to get around my city."